# Question related to number of distinct forcing extensions of a countable model

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, forcing

***A bit of context:*** the below question is motivated by roughly the following scenario: we have some countable model $\mathcal{M}$, and want to “count” the number of functions/sets $f$ such that $\mathcal{M}[f]$ (in the sense of a forcing extension) is a “mostly-elementary” extension; I’m curious if the number of such extensions can ever be less then the continuum, under the negation of the continuum hypothesis. However the context i’m working in is weak arithmetic so the definition of “forcing extension” and “model” are a bit different then in the standard set-theoretic forcing where this question is (presumably?) already well-understood.

***Formal question:*** Say we have a countable system of “constraints”:
$$\mathcal{C} = \{C_i \subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$$
where each constraint is “finitely meetable” in the following sense: we say a constraint $C$ is finitely meetable if for any finite partial function $r: [n] \to \mathbb{N}$, there is some finite extension $\hat{r}: [m] \to \mathbb{N}, m \geq n$ of $r$ such that whenever $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ agrees with $\hat{r}$ we have that $f \in C$ (I imagine there is a standard name for this, as this type of contraint arises naturally in Cohen forcing, which is where the motivation comes from).

We will say that $f: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ “satisfies the constraint $C_i$” if $f \in C_i$, and that it satisfies $\mathcal{C}$ if it satisfies every $C_i \in \mathcal{C}$. My question is now, what can we say in general about the number of functions which satisfy $\mathcal{C}$? Under the continuum hypothesis the answer is always the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$, since:

(1) There are at most $\mathfrak{c}$-many functions $f: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$

(2) There are at least uncountably many by a basic diagonalization argument: say we had some countable family $\mathcal{F} = \{f_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of functions satisfying $\mathcal{C}$. Then we can build a new satisfying function outside of $\mathcal{F}$ by extending some finite partial function piece by piece, on even steps extending enough to satisfy some constraint $C_i$, and on odd steps extending enough to differ from some $f_i$.

However, it is not clear to me how to strengthen this second argument to show unconditionally that there are at least $\mathfrak{c}$-many satisfying functions, and I’m curious if there could be a possible countable system of constraints $\mathcal{C}$ which admits say, only $\aleph_1$ many satisfying assignments, and thus less then $\mathfrak{c}$ assuming the negation of CH?

Comment: Being “finitely meetable” is equivalent to being dense in the forcing to add one Cohen real. To show there are continuum-many generics, build a perfect tree of where at level $n$ there are $2^n$ many incompatible paths meeting the first $n$ constraints.

Comment: Ah yes, that is quite simple. thank you.